# No output when selecting a dropdown menu using python selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I want to select all the option values from a dropdown menu, but when selecting the latter no output appears. Any ideas why is this happening?

Html Code:

```
<select class="Combo" id="cmbSecciones" onchange="FiltrarCombos(this,this.item(this.selectedIndex).value);LlenarComboCargo(this,this.item(this.selectedIndex).value)
```

My code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Administrador/Documents/chromedriver')
main_url = 'https://www.justiciacordoba.gob.ar/Estatico/JEL/Escrutinios/ReportesEleccion20190512/default.html'
driver.get(main_url)

driver.switch_to.frame("topFrame")
dropdown= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cmbSecciones"]')
dropdown
```

output:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="34e889c18eb0b5f5dbe6a18d6107389e", element="245e4c6a-e564-460e-9dd9-d678c7028c2d")>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are printing `webelement` not the option values.

To get all option values use this code.

```
dropdown= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cmbSecciones"]')
select_box = Select(dropdown)
for item  in select_box.options:
    print(item.get_attribute('value'))
```

Or you can do without `select` class to print all options

```
dropdown= driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="cmbSecciones"]//option')
for item  in dropdown:
    print(item.get_attribute('value'))
```

Comment: but the problem is that when selecting the dropdown (with find_element_by_xpath) even though no error arises, I dont get any output. So then there is nothing to select. Now I realize that I may not have been clear when posting the problem.

Comment: @EmilioChambouleyron : Check updated answer is that you are after? If not then please post your expected out in your original post.Thanks.